# How to replace empirical frequency predictions with Laplace estimates

Tags: laplace-smoothing

I have frequency predictions for a discrete distribution:

$p(x_1)=0$,  $p(x_2)=0$, $p(x_3)=0.05$, $p(x_4)=0.95$

I need to smooth the distribution so I don't have zero values. I think the solution is to use the Lapalace additive smoothing function:
$(x_i + \alpha) / (N + \alpha*d)$

But I am unsure what values to use for $N$ and $d$. I guess $d$ is the domain size?

This is supposed to be basic, but I can't seem to find a clear answer.

$N$ is supposed to be the number of samples, but I don't have any samples, just this distribution.

Comment: If you don't know anything about how the frequency estimates were derived, then there is no meaningful way of "smoothing" the distribution.  You have no way of knowing how accurate those estimates are.

Comment: I do know, but I don't think what I know is helpful. These are the frequency estimates submitted by a single person. I have many such estimates; each person submitted his/her own estimate.